# Объясните ошибку android

Tags: android

У меня есть несколько вопросов по поводу ошибки код которой вы можете увидеть ниже:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.SecondScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0040
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0040
 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
 at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:543)
 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(Toolbar.java:903)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.setActionBarDescription(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:608)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:600)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:495)
 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:242)
 at com.example.developer_4.test_login.SecondScreen.onCreate(SecondScreen.java:75)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
 ... 9 more
```

Но начнем сначала, данное приложение тестировалось на нескольких виртуальных и на нескольких реальных устройствах. Проблема в чем, на большинстве телефонов все работает нормально, но вот уже на двух устройствах происходят непонятные мне изменения в работе приложения. Во-первых, что самое странное, это то что приложение не подгружает ресурсы, вообще никакие, картинки (я вставил иконку свою), строковые ресурсы тоже не видит, может еще что-то не грузит я не знаю. Но самое обидное что программа не выполняет свою главную задачу. Вот есть такой код:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(activity_login);

                submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendPost();
                    }
                });

                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                        handleUncaughtException(thread, ex);
                    }
                });

        }

        public void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
            String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
            String message = e.getMessage();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"angoran16@gmail.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MyApp Crash log file");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stackTrace);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // required when starting from Application
            startActivity(intent);
        }

public void sendPost() {
        final EditText titleEt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final EditText bodyEt = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final String a = titleEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final String b = bodyEt.getText().toString().trim();
        final Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        //retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.auth(new Post(a, b)).enqueue(new Callback<GetToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<GetToken> call, @NonNull Response<GetToken> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    //TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.access_token);
                    String token = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAccess_token();
                    //txt.setText(token);
                    startActivity(intent);


                    tok_pref = getSharedPreferences("access_token", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = tok_pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
                    editor.commit();


                    saveData();

                    titleEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                            if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                                findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                            } else {
                                btn.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                                      int after) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
            }
```

то есть как видно из кода, при нажатии на кнопку у меня отправляется запрос на сервер. В проблемных телефонах при нажатии на кнопку, вроде как запрос отправляется но дальше приложение падает.

### UPDATE

Вот файл моего SecondScreen:

```
    package com.example.developer_4.test_login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.PagerAdapter;
import com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Received;
import com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Sent;

public class SecondScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Received.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Sent.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Received"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Sent"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

если проблема в layout файле, то у меня их несколько, так как я добавлял активити nawdrawer.

Спасибо всем за ценные советы, ответы и критику)). Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: `//txt.setText(token);` это вы закрыли до или после?

Comment: Не понял до или после чего? Я просто его сделал не активным, чтобы он не показывал текст.

Comment: Ну ошибку у вас выдает, даже в том случае, когда txt.setText(token); комментирован? У вас ошибка где-то в String

Comment: Да я заметил что ошибка с string но я не могу понять как строки могут привести к падению приложения, да ресурсы не Грузии но чтобы так действовать на работу приложения? Это круто по-моему...

Comment: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"angoran16@gmail.com"});` - попробуйте эту строку в виде простого стринга передать, а не массива

Comment: Нет ошибка я думаю не из-за этого, дело в том что уже после падения пытаюсь внедрить отправку ошибки по почте. То есть сначала приложение упало, а потом появилась вся та конструкция по отправке лога.

Comment: Ошибка, скорее всего, вызвана тем, что в лейаут файле `activity_login` используется ссылка на строковый ресурс специфичный к версии support библиотеки...

Покажите свой лейаут

Comment: Пердпологаю - что код соответствует `LoginActivity` - но по ошибке - нужен код из `SecondScreen`

Comment: а как мне решить какой код добавлять? я в том плане что у меня есть несколько layout файлов - я просто добавлял активити nawdrawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче я долго сидел... весь проект перелопатил, потом у меня появилась идея создать подписанный apk-файл и закинуть на проблемный телефон, и все ок. Все ресурсы загрузились и все работало нормально.